# XML to CSV but same tags under parent

Tags: python, excel, xml

I have an XML file like that and trying to convert it to CSV with xml2csv python library. But there is a < images > image tag that brokes everything. I want to get all < img_item > tags on different column. How can I achieve that?

Thanks,

```
<products>
    <product>
        <code>722</code>
        <ws_code>B515C16CRU</ws_code>
        <supplier_code>B515C16CRU</supplier_code>
        <images>
            <img_item type_name="">
            https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3378-72-B.jpg
            </img_item>
            <img_item type_name="">
            https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3379-72-B.jpg
            </img_item>
            <img_item type_name="">
            https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3380-72-B.jpg
            </img_item>
        </images>
    </product>
    .... 
</products>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import re

class xml_to_csv:
def do(self):
   #self.xml_file_location = input("Enter full path of XML file(Eg =                   D:\programs\ResidentData.xml) : ")
   self.tree = ET.parse("urunler-fotolu.xml")
   self.root = self.tree.getroot()
   self.csv_file_location = input("Enter full path to store CSV file(Eg = D:\programs\csv_file.csv ) : ")
   self.csv_data = open(self.csv_file_location, 'w')
   self.csv_writer = csv.writer(self.csv_data)
   self.find_records(self.root)

def find_attributes(self,record):
   temp = []
   dont_do = 0
   for j in record:
       temp = temp + self.find_attributes(j)
       dont_do = 1
   if(dont_do == 0):
       return [record.text]
   return temp

def find_records(self,root1):
    for i in root1:
        csv_record = self.find_attributes(i)

        sz = len(csv_record)
        i=0
        while (i<sz):
            if csv_record[i][0] == '\n':
                 csv_record[i] = csv_record[i][1:len(csv_record[i])-1]
            i = i+1;
        print(csv_record)
        self.csv_writer.writerow(csv_record)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = xml_to_csv()
    obj.do()
```

Input:

```
For this = """
     <State>
       <Resident Id="100">
          <Name>Sample Name</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
          <EmailAddress>sample_name@example.com</EmailAddress
          <Address>
                        <StreetLine1>Street Line1</StreetLine1>
                        <City>City Name</City>
                        <StateCode>AE</StateCode>
                        <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
          </Address>
     </Resident>
     </State>
"""
```

Output :

```
  ['Sample Name', '1234567891', 'sample_name@example.com', 'Street Line1', 'City Name', 'AE', '12345']
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185955/discussion-on-answer-by-bubesh-p-xml-to-csv-but-same-tags-under-parent).

Answer (score 0):

As you might have guessed, the problem is because each `product` node has multiple `img_item` tags which `xml2csv` does not know how to handle (and, going over its documentation, does not seem to have an option to let it know how to handle these nodes).

You can, however, do this quite easily using the builtin `csv` module. You just need to decide how you want to delimit the different images' urls. In the example below I've decided to use `;` (obviously you can't use `,`, unless you use another delimiter for the columns).

Also note that I hardcoded the headers. This can be (quite) easily changed so that the headers are dynamically detected from the `product` node's sub-elements.

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

string = '''<products>
    <product>
        <code>722</code>
        <ws_code>B515C16CRU</ws_code>
        <supplier_code>B515C16CRU</supplier_code>
        <images>
            <img_item type_name="">https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3378-72-B.jpg</img_item>
            <img_item type_name="">https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3379-72-B.jpg</img_item>
            <img_item type_name="">https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3380-72-B.jpg</img_item>
        </images>
    </product>
</products>'''

root = ET.fromstring(string)

headers = ('code', 'ws_code', 'supplier_code', 'images')

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    for product in root.iter('product'):
        writer.writerow({'code': product.find('code').text,
                         'ws_code': product.find('ws_code').text,
                         'supplier_code': product.find('supplier_code').text,
                         'images': ';'.join(img.text for img in product.iter('img_item'))})
```

Which produces the below CSV:

```
code,ws_code,supplier_code,images
722,B515C16CRU,B515C16CRU,https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3378-72-B.jpg;https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3379-72-B.jpg;https://www.apparel.com.tr/stance-corap-cruker-grey-orap-stance-ankle-bters-3380-72-B.jpg
```

Comment: I'm getting `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 28, column 2` error on my console.

Comment: @Omercan Which means that the XML file you are trying to use is, well, `not well-formed`

Comment: I'm sure it is well formatted. Because xml2csv is giving output.

Comment: @Omercan Add the **actual** file you are trying to parse properly formatted to your question.

Comment: here is the link: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LUGrj8ezQFMPuwyLxCw7lp71vbuRb-S4/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: @Omercan Add it to the question. No one wants to click on an arbitrary link

Comment: It is too big. 4.8 mb